# Vim: sort al use statements inside a php file

Tags: php, sorting, vim

I'll like to learn how to select all lines that starts with use, inside current php file, and then sort them. Until now: I've worked with :sort command. Also, ... I've remapped sort command:

```
map <Leader>s :sort<CR>
```

But I'll like to create a complex function that select all use statements inside a php file, and after that, that sort all that lines.

I know how to sort. But I have no idea of what is the way to select some arbitrary group of strings with VimL

```
function! SortUseStatements()
    let g:select='/^use .*$<CR>V' !?!?!?!?!?!?!?!?!?
    exec g:select
endfunction

map <F2> :call SortUseStatements()<CR>
```

I know that I want to execute commands like:

- go to the beginning of current file
- sarch first ^use .*;$ statement
- start selection
- go to the end of current file
- sarch last ^use .*;$ statement
- and finally, run :sort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be neatly done with `:help cmdline-ranges`.

You want the search to start at the beginning of the file, so your initial address is `0` (to start before the first line). Then, search for the first line beginning with `use`. When separated with `;` the cursor position will be set to that line before interpreting the next line specifier. Then, you need to navigate to the last of the `use` statements (starting from the first `use` line, so again separated by `;`). I first choose an easy way that searches for an empty line, and then takes the previous one. With `:print`, you can check that the range is fine before replacing the command with `:sort`:

```
:0;/^use /;/^$/-1 print
```

If there's no empty line after the `use` block, you have to use a more complex pattern for *any line not starting with `use`*:

```
:0;/^use /;/^\(use \)\@!/-1 print
```

#### Alternatives

For anything more complex, a single `:range` probably won't do. I would then determine the start and end line numbers separately, using `let lnum = search(...)` with appropriate patterns. Then you can insert the numbers into an Ex command via `:execute startLnum . ',' . endLnum . 'sort'`

Comment: Mmmm nice, ... Can you help to improve the script? I am trying with ":0;/^namespace /;/^class /-1:sort". But I'll like to leave an empty line after namespace string and before class. Is it possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what your data looks like... If those empty lines have to be included in the sorted range, I'd delete all of them (`:0;/^namespace /;/^class /-1 global/^$/delete`) and then selectively re-add them: `:0;/^namespace /put =''`.